# Yolo V8 Not taking training data

Tags: yolo, yolov8

I am using YOLOV8n model to train from scratch. Here I have dataset  containing train , valid, test folders . Its access for model is given through data.yaml file but the issue is that model is not training on the dataset/train because in train folder I have 79 images yolo is considering only 9 images which is in valid folder...

the dataset is generated through roboflow for yolo txt file and path in data.yaml is also correct
What could be the reason please help!!

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that everything runs smoothly, you should first check your folder structure. Here are some steps that you can follow:

1. Create three empty folders named train, val, and test.
2. In each of these folders, create two folders named "images" and "labels".
3. Put your images and annotations in the respective folders.
4. Make sure to modify the paths accordingly when running the program.

Following these steps will help you get started without any issues.

[You can use this for reference](https://youtu.be/m9fH9OWn8YM?si=Fv6XTYc0U3HqauFV)